# Angular multiple api call issue

Tags: angularjs, httprequest, angular-services, angular-controller

In my controller, I am calling a service that is making an http request to an api that returns a JSON file with my analytics data.

This is my service:

```
.factory('getData', ['$http', function($http) {
return {
    getFacebookData: getFacebookData,
};

function getFacebookData(clientName) {
   return $http.get('/blah.com/'+clientName)
    .then(getDataComplete)
    .catch(getDataFailed);

   function getDataComplete(response) {
    return response.data[0].facebook;
   }

   function getDataFailed(error) {
     console.log(error);
   }
}
```

Then my controller calls the service like this:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $http, getData) {
var clientName = "blah"
getData.getFacebookData(clientName)
    .then(function(data) {
    console.log("facebook:", data)
});
```

The problem I am having is that in the console, it is making the request and logging the data 6 times.  This may be a dumb question, but any advice on why its doing this and how to only make the request once would be awesome.

Comment: What browser are you using?  Are you API's on 2 different servers?

Comment: Chrome, and no, its just one server.

Comment: have you tried a different browser?  I know Chrome has some funny issues with chrome.

Comment: Check for multiple ng-view attributes.

Comment: @Dave there can be only one `ng-view` property would allow on single page.

Comment: If you say so, but the last time I had code executing multiple times for no apparent reason, it was because of multiple ng-view attributes.  Also: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5710

Comment: There is only one ```ng-view```. I added another one, it just repeats the same content twice and does double the requests.

Comment: What if you just put a `console.log()` in the controller, outside the `then()`?  does it perform that multiple times too?